# Why is Lubuntu 12.04 so slow to start up and shut down on my Mac Powerbook G4?

Tags: 12.04, lubuntu, mac, powerpc, ppc

I just installed Lubuntu 12.04 on a Mac Powerbook G4 12 inch laptop (G4 867 MHz Powerbook with 640 Megs RAM and an 80 gig HD). It works, but just barely, with a painfully slow shutdown (about 3 minutes) and an equally painful boot up (5 minutes). Once it boots, applications are reasonably responsive.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Pastebin the output of `dmesg` please.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Lubuntu is supposed to be much faster than Ubuntu, but it's just slower. Now one actually knows why it's slower, although people think the problem is the following:

The desktop that Lubuntu's  LXDE desktop is based on, tries to start certain services, but are replaced with LXDE's services. It's this replacement that slows Lubuntu down.

That is what other people think the speed issue is caused by.

Answer (score 1):

I have a powerbook G4 550 mhz, 512 mb ram, and i don't have such a delays. Sorry mi english, not english-speaker. My system is up and running in about 2 minutes, and shuts down in less than 1 minute. Perhaps there is something wrong with your system? Perhaps hard drive is failing?